# How can I block new plugins from installing on Mozilla browsers (to prevent installation of malicious plugins)?

Tags: firefox

"[Make your Firefox faster, safer and stable with few mouse clicks](http://thesunstroke.blogspot.com/2010/07/make-your-firefox-faster-and-stable.html)
"article says that many companies installs really DANGEROUS plugins in Firefox. I love Firefox but I must admit that it is a security risk since it allows plugin installation so easily. It should at least pop-up a message like "A plugin was installed stealthy. Do you want to disable it?"

My question is (because I don't really want to uninstall Firefox) **how can I make Firefox not to accept new plugins**? Maybe if I delete some files I can cripple Firefox plugin system until it is not working at all - but Firefox still works. I looked in my installed plugins (indeed I have that dangerous plugin installed) and I need none of them!

Comment: I think "really DANGEROUS" is a bit over the top. I've looked where the article says and never found anything there that was dangerous or even unreasonable. Have you had problems with Firefox being compromised? It looks like the java one is the only one to consider getting rid of due to the security vulnerability. You can update java to fix that though.

Comment: "A plugin was installed stealthy...." - can a plugin be installed _stealthily_? I always get a warning. Plugins are one of the best things about Firefox. TBH, if it wasn't for the plugins I'd probably be using one of the other browsers.

Comment: @"Plugins are one of the best things about Firefox"  -  Agree but not all of them. In my computer FF accepts all plugins without rising an eyebrow!

Comment: I wouldn't trust the blog you linked either, it kind of looks like a fake site made by a PR company (a not-very-professional one)

Comment: @MGOwen - I don't see a problem with that blog. It is just citing other sources of information. Some of them ARE RELIABLE (like CNet)! Well, unless you have better sources that those plugins are NOT dangerous. All in all, Firefox just blocked Java for a CRITICAL security bug (which got my computer infected for the first time in years).

Comment: @w3d: Plug-ins, as in Flash Player, not extensions, as in Adblock Plus. They can be installed without notification by third-party software.

Comment: @musicfreak - ah, yes, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: "REALLY toxic" is too sensationalist. The blog you reference looks pretty poor quality and references some old information, and seems to suggest that the Java JDK was someone installed on his machine without permission, which I highly doubt. Sun/Oracle is strict about distributing the JDK due to intellectual property issues, and they wouldn't just install it willy-nilly on people's browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** ok sorry my answer may not be very readable but it incorporates several original research results that I **successfully** used in personal scope **to block new plugins, while retaining addons**.

### ultra short version

- there is now a restartless **extension** called [new plugin disabler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-plugin-disabler/). *it will disable each new plugin on startup!* (most handy)

### short version (additionally):

- you can revoke write rights, keeping only read rights, from everyone (including the user 'Everyone') for `<Firefox installation dir>/plugins`. This would prevent any plugins from *directory-based* installing (as long as an installer doesn't replace the rights), except the few four that Firefox is prepared to know about.
- you can try setting `plugin.scan.plid.all` to `false` in `about:config`. This disables firefox *registry-based* scanning for new plugins.
- *click to play:* you can make firefox *ask* you each time a site needs a plugin whether to activate it. In `about:config` set `plugin.default.state` to `1` ([meaning](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/base/nsIPluginTag.idl) "clicktoplay"), and also set `plugins.click_to_play` to `true`.
- when using windows, for configuring directory permissions, you can use [`cacls`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) with `psexec` (link below) for system-level access, or perhaps the permission listing on right-click properties' security tab
- when using windows, for extra registry protection, rewoke write rights, keep read rights for 
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`,
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`. you can use regedit with the [tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) `psexec -s -i regedit.exe` (or `regedt32.exe`).

### *very* long version

**update 2014/06**

additionally to my original answer:

- `click_to_play` were [mixed in 885357](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885357) with `plugin.default.state`. you want to set `plugin.default.state` to `1` meaning "clicktoplay" or `0` meaning "disabled". the possible values are here in [source/dom/plugins/base/nsIPluginTag.idl](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/base/nsIPluginTag.idl)
- there is now a restartless **extension/addon** called [new plugin disabler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-plugin-disabler/)
- `plugin.expose_full_path` is gone in newer versions
- [`security.xpconnect.plugin.unrestricted`](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=153889) may or may not be related
- `9999.0` too seems to be a valid value to minimum version. with todays media-hyped "increment version number per month" strategies `99.0` may be not enough, albeit I doubt the sales power of version 139 and `9999.0` still could cause surprise if it ever gets invalidated as a version.
- [`gecko.handlerService.defaultHandlersVersion`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gecko.handlerService.defaultHandlersVersion) and [`MimeTypes.rdf`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) can also induce program execution. there may or may not be other relevant concepts.

even more additional info:

- mozilla has dedicated technical privacy reviews https://wiki.mozilla.org/Privacy/Reviews which may be relevant to you
- this is out of scope but if you are an administrator or just curious you may want to consider creating an *update policy*. firefox now has an [extended support release (esr)](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) intended for organizations.
- additionally you may be interested in ["firefox lockdown"](http://ilias.ca/blog/2005/03/locking-mozilla-firefox-settings/) or this [other link on pcc-services.com](http://www.pcc-services.com/kixtart/firefox-lockdown.html) like `lockPref`, `mozilla.cfg` and co.
- additionally you may want to know about [customizing firefox default profiles](http://mike.kaply.com/2012/03/30/customizing-firefox-default-profiles/) (unofficial by mike kaply)
- additionally current `about:config` entries of interest regarding update may include `extensions.update.enabled`, `plugins.update.notifyUser`, `extensions.update.autoUpdateDefault`, `browser.search.update`, `app.update.service.enabled`, `app.update.silent`, `app.update.enabled`, `app.update.staging.enabled`, `app.update.url`, `services.sync.prefs.sync.app.update.mode`, `app.update.channel`, `app.update.auto` and `app.update.mode` for which you can get a hint of possible values in for example [`source/browser/components/preferences/in-content/advanced.js`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/preferences/in-content/advanced.js#562), `2` being roughly `warn` for mode, and `false` meaning ask for `auto`, and more eg. `app.update.incompatible.mode` with hint of values in [source/browser/app/profile/firefox.js](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/app/profile/firefox.js#217), etc.
- you can search the source code for stuff in the great [mozilla cross reference (mxr)](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) in the sky

---

**original answer**

There's actually a way to **prevent** some, or all, **plugins** from "installing" **but keep addons** in Firefox. The problem is that on Windows, [Firefox *scans* for plugins](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugin_scanning) on some locations. On each of these locations can reside one or more plugins.

**You can control how Firefox treats each of these locations but you cannot control how it treats individual plugins if the location lists more than one.** Doing this involves multiple methods. Not all are nice.

Before getting into it, 
it's worth to mention that there is also **[click to play](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Issues_related_to_plugins#Click_to_Play)**, that will ask you to *click* before activating any plugin individually, if a webpage asks for any. It can be found in `about:config` as `plugins.click_to_play`. You can set it to `true`.

Now, first the nicer parts:

You shall go to the `about:config` page and filter for **plugin.scan**. Here, *plid* means a registry key location. The rest is for plugins that are handled individually.

```
plugin.scan.SunJRE", "1.3"
plugin.scan.Acrobat", "5.0"
plugin.scan.Quicktime", "5.0"
plugin.scan.WindowsMediaPlayer", "7.0"
plugin.scan.plid.all", true
```

The "1.3", etc. is the minimum version number that Firefox accepts. 
The recommendation is that for plugins you want to disable, set this value to `19.0`. I've set it to `99.0` and it works in Firefox 18.

You can check the actual location of these plugins by the means [described](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Issues_related_to_plugins#Plugin_location) on Mozilla's KB. The idea is that you go to the `about:plugins` page to see active plugin's location. But you need to set `plugin.expose_full_path` to `true` first.

To disable *all* registry-based plugin location scan, set `plugin.scan.plid.all` to `false`. The actual registry key is [described on another page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry#Plugins) the KB. I listed the keys later.

If you ever need to reset these *about:config* settings, right click on them and choose reset.

Now for the uglier part:

Firefox will look for plugins in `<Firefox installation dir>/plugins`. This was where plugins like Acrobat, QuickTime and Office installed themselves in my computer.

The setting that was controlling this directory was removed. That's why I choose to modify the access rights of this directory. **Set the rights for all users to read-only.** Then no new program will be able to write to it.

I guess you could do the same with the registry key, too. The actual registry keys are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id

And on 64-bit Windows:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id
```

(To set permission on a registry key, you right-click it and go for "Permissions...". You shall see it, but if don't try starting regedit with the [tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) `psexec -s -i regedit.exe` or using `regedt32.exe` if I recall it well.)

Just for the record, I've removed all access from the system user for the plugins dir, and Firefox didn't crash. Any new installation may, though.

For archiving purposes, I include the full url's as text here:

<sub>plugin scanning:  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugin_scanning .
registry key: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry#Plugins .
location: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Issues_related_to_plugins#Plugin_location .</sub>

I've found these articles by browsing a category page listing all kind of interesting articles: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Category:Plugins

Comment: Wow. Such a complex answer. Many Firefox users won't understand this (as they understand how dangerous Firefox and its plugin system can be). +1 for your documented answer!

Comment: Happy to see you find it useful! I wish it weren't this complicated. At least anyone can guess what is what she/he is dealing with in today's technology. Hoping one day Mozilla dedicates itself to a prioritize privacy and security even more, implementing and maintaining an easy and long-term fix to this. Until then, I hope the technically minded with a will to descend this path may find some pieces useful. Hopefully these will make it a step more hard to circumvent security.

Comment: It will be easy for Firefox to eliminate this threat. They should not accept ALL plugins in the folder but only once that have been installed via its plugin installer interface.  Yes. IT IS that easy.

Comment: @Altar Yes doesn't seem that hard to fix does it? Wonder what keeps them. Maybe one just would need to file a bug/feature request. Is the *plugin installer interface* of Firefox something that's available and has a reference?

Comment: I mean, when you drag and drop a plug in file (xpi) into firefox. Firefox will pop-up a message to ask you if you want to install that plug in. So, firefox is AWARE that user wanted to install THAT plug in. It should be aware about plugins that ware not explicitly installed by the user.

Comment: @Altar I see, you're right they could make the barrier higher based on that. Albeit I wonder what could prevent a malicious out-of-firefox plugin installer from modifying firefox's internal data file, eg. when firefox is *not* running. Still that barrier would be higher than the current. But regardless it'd remain something that could use some kind of extra protection mechanism.

Comment: Please keep your edits substantial. Editing the answer pushes it to the front page, and trivial edits don't add any relevant new stuff.

Answer (score 3):

To disable all of Firefox's add-ons, you have to open the browser in its Safe Mode (no relation to Windows' own Safe Mode) by clicking **Start > All Programs > Mozilla Firefox > Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode).**

> In the Firefox Safe Mode dialog box that appears before Firefox opens, click "Disable all add-ons" and choose the Make Changes and Restart button to run the browser with no add-ons or extensions enabled.

A quicker way is to press the Windows key (in XP, follow this by pressing R), type Firefox -safe-mode, and press Enter.

Comment: Is this answer what you are looking for? If so, please accept the question. And upvote if you want ;)

Comment: I think I rather aim for "how can I make Firefox not to accept anymore plugins"

Comment: Plugins are suggested to you. It's your own decision to install them or not. So basically, you can't just disable add-ins auto-install feature (Because there's none) in firefox

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to disable automatic plugin installation. All the user can do to prevent against this extremely dangerous Firefox loophole is to check the plugin list every few days (which I do).

Comment: you can revoke write rights, keeping only read rights, from Everyone for `<Firefox installation dir>/plugins`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`,
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id`, and set `plugin.scan.plid.all` to `false` in `about:config`

Answer (score 0):

**In Firefox options menu, just choose the security tab and make sure "Warn me when sites try to install add-ons" is ticked.**

Not sure why or how you turned it off, but that should fix it.

Odd that Firefox allows this at all - shouldn't be an option in my opinion, though I understand why there is an exceptions list.

Comment: The plugins were installed by local software and not by web sites.

Comment: OK, that makes a pretty big difference. Please edit the question to make it clear that there is a difference between add-ons installed by web sites and plug-ins installed by other apps on your local computer.

Comment: Well, you should look up for these definitions by yourself. I didn't invented them. They are standard. There is nothing to clarify.